# smartgwt button cannot override skin_styles.css

Tags: css, styles, smartgwt, skinning

I want to add red background and white color for titleStyle for ibutton in smartgwt. I cannot override skin_styles.css. How to override skin_styles for button in smartgwt? Simple addStyleName() or setPrimaryStyleName does not work. Have somebody tried it?setBase Style also.

Comment: It seems you have issues with skinning and style:

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have issues with skinning and style, If you want to add a style to a widget(your previous post) you can use some sort of code:

```
    String newStyle;
    String actualStyle= o.getStyleName();
    if(actualStyle!= null){
         newStyle= actualStyle+ " " + styleNameYouWant;
    }else{
        newStyle= styleNameYouWant;
    }
    o.setStyleName(newStyle);
```