# smart gwt style attribute

Tags: css, gwt, attributes, styles, smartgwt

I cannot change attributes of HTMLFlow, i would like to use my defined css for the HTMLFlow and then setAttribute for FontSize in the constructor but nothing changes. 
First I extend HMTLFlow like this.

```
class MyHTMLFlow extends HTMLFlow{
public MyHTMLFLow(width, fontSize){
setStyle("myHtmlFlow");
//here i tried all posibilites but nothing works
setAttribute("fontSize",fontSize);
getElement().getStyle().setProperty("fontSize",fontSize);
//the width works ok
setWidth(width);

}

.myHtmlFlow{
width:250;
font-size:12px;
}
```

Please help me to make HTMLFlow size defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use setStyleName, I used this and it works:

```
HTMLFlow newsFlow = new HTMLFlow();
newsFlow .setPadding(7);
newsFlow .setStyleName("plSectionText");
```

with my css:

```
.plSectionText {
font-size: 1.3em;
```

}

Comment: will the previous style be overriden?I want it to stay the same.

Comment: If you don't want it overriden you have to concatenate the actual style to the one you want to add. In my case I use a utility with static method like in my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183111/smartgwt-button-cannot-override-skin-styles-css/9189137#9189137