# Layouting an IconButton Smart GWT

Tags: gwt, button, smartgwt, styling

Is it possible to change the padding or margin between the icon and the title of the IconButton? I want the text in the button to appear a bit further away from the icon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the style you can have a look [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183111/smartgwt-button-cannot-override-skin-styles-css)
If you want to modify the look of all your IconButton you can change your skin.